# Atomicity with AWS S3 Writes and Reads

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sftp

I have a SFTP server that use AWS S3 for storage. There are folders on the SFTP server that are mapped to corresponding S3 Objects. Multiple applications write files to the SFTP Server/S3 at unknown intervals and there is a process that periodically reads the S3 objects. In a way, S3 is being used as a queue.

Lets say I start uploading a file/writing to a S3 Object. If there is an HTTP GET or READ request on S3Object while the write is in progress, will you see the partial object?
I performed a test where I was uploading a large file to SFTP server and ran aws s3 ls command and I could see the uploaded file listed although the upload was not completed.

I know S3 has read-after-write consistency with HTTP PUT methods but how does this work in general?

Comment: The answer I would give is not consistent with your observations... so, questions: Are you using s3fs on the SFTP server?  Could you check your S3 bucket logs (enable them if you haven't) and see what the SFTP server is doing under the hood?  It could be that you're actually writing objects to S3 in a non-atomic fashion, i.e., doing multiple writes as the file is created, giving the impression that S3 is behaving less atomically than it should.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am using s3fs. I will check on the S3 bucket logs and report back.